# How to highlight the recently edited lines on the right side of the editor

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to get the recently edited lines or blocks highlighted on the right side the way an error,or warning or a TODO is highlighted as given in the below screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the *Quick Diff* Feature:

*Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Quick Diff*

Here you can set whether to show the quick diff in the left and/or right ruler, what colors to use, and what base version to diff against, e.g. since last save, or different types of version control.

[image]

If you are using version control, such as GIT or SVN, you can have a similar effect by selecting *Team -> Show Annotations* from the context menu.

Comment: @DivyaMV I guess so, since when I uncheck that option the indicator on the right disappears.